# How to get the control id from master page to contentpage in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am trying to access the master page control id into the content page.

tried with findcontrol and its working, but not understanding the below case.

In master page I have 100 hyperlinks are there, based on click of one of the hyperlink I would like to display the content in content page.

if I know control name then can go for findcontrol, but in this case I don't know which link has been clicked.

any body could you share any resolution criteria.

Comment: You can use Property as string and update that property on each click with the controlID  and then access it on the content page

Comment: Thanks for the info i will try this seems good to listen.

Comment: If this does not work you can go for the query string also.